# Custom WP Query for woocommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress

Getting parameters is query string and using them in wp query and also used tax and meta query for filters
need to create sort by: popular, Date and Price using wp query i am getting everything in query string so confused how should i sort or order by using query string

```
if($starting_amount || $ending_amount || $animal || $activity || $hunting_method || $arrival_date || $departure_date || $product_cat || $orderby):
                            $args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'product',
                                'post_status' => 'publish',
                                'order' => 'DESC',
                                'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
                                'tax_query' => array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy'  => 'animal',
                                        'terms'  => $animal,
                                        'field'  => 'id',
                                        'include_children' => true,
                                        'operator' => ($animal != '') ? 'IN' : 'NOT IN',
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy'  => 'activity',
                                        'terms'  => $activity,
                                        'field'  => 'id',
                                        'include_children' => true,
                                        'operator' => ($activity != '') ? 'IN' : 'NOT IN',
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy'  => 'hunting-method',
                                        'terms'  => $hunting_method,
                                        'field'  => 'id',
                                        'include_children' => true,
                                        'operator' => ($hunting_method != '') ? 'IN' : 'NOT IN',
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
                                        'terms'  => $product_cat,
                                        'field'  => 'slug',
                                        'include_children' => true,
                                        'operator' => ($product_cat != '') ? 'IN' : 'NOT IN',
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'meta_query' => array(
                                    'relation' => 'OR',
                                    array(
                                        'key' => '_price',
                                        'value' => array($starting_amount, $ending_amount),
                                        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                                        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'key' => 'total_sales',
                                        'value' => array($starting_amount, $ending_amount),
                                        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                                        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'relation' => 'OR',
                                        array(
                                            'key' => 'arrival_date',
                                            'value' => $new_arrival_date,
                                            'meta_compare'=> ($arrival_date != '') ? '==' : '>=',
                                            'type'=>'DATE',
                                        ),
                                        array(
                                            'key' => 'departure_date',
                                            'value' => $new_departure_date,
                                            'meta_compare'=> ($departure_date != '') ? '==' : '>=',
                                            'type'=>'DATE',
                                        )
                                    )
                                ),
                                'orderby' => 'date',
                                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            );
                        else:
                            $args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'product',
                                'post_status' => 'publish',
                                'order' => 'DESC',
                                'orderby' => 'date',
                                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            );
                        endif;
```

just need sort by or order by functionality

Comment: Thanks for coming to SO to ask your question! A good practice is to specify your desired output (what should it contain? what should it look like? what does "ordered" mean for you in this case? etc.). Also, it would help people diagnose your issue if you explained a bit more about what you have tried and what did not work about those attempts.

Comment: i am showing list of packages

Comment: need to sorting using wp query

Comment: I would recommend editing the question so that it conforms to the suggestions here: [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)